# I don't understand pointers

Tags: c, pointers

What is a pointer? What is dereferencing? If `p` is a pointer, what is the difference between `*p = some_value` and `p = other_value`? What does `p = &some_variable` mean? What is a NULL pointer? What happens when you dereference a NULL pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get a stack of yellow sticky notes, a pencil, an eraser, and a pen.

Take a sticky note. Divide it with a horizontal line. Write "note #1" on it with a **pen** in the top part. (This mark is permanent). Write "7" with a **pencil** in the bottom part. Stick it to the top left corner of your computer screen.

[image]

This note represents a memory location that stores the integer value 7. The top part is the **address**. Each location has its own unique permanent address. The bottom part is the **value** being stored.

Take another note, divide it in two areas, and similarly write "note #2" and "13" on it. Stick it to your screen next to the first one. This is another memory location that stores an integer value, 13 this time.

[image] [image]

Now take another note. In the "address" part of the note write "note #3". In the "value" part of the note write "*note #1*" (use the pencil!). You have just created a **pointer**. Stick it next to the first two notes.

[image] [image] [image]

Now write down a couple of shorthands on a separate piece of paper:

```
a    int     #1
b    int     #2
p    int*    #3
```

This represents a *symbol table*. `a`, `b` and `p` are *variable names`. In the next column we have their types, and the third column contains their addresses.

Now let's do some C statements.

```
a = 77;
```

Look up `a` in your symbol table. It is #1. Erase the value part of this note and write `77` instead (that's where the eraser comes handy).

[image] [image] [image]

```
b = 2017;
```

This is completely analogous to the previous one.

[image] [image] [image]

```
a = b;
```

Look up `a` and `b` in your symbol table. They are #1 and #2 respectively. See what note #2 has in its "value" part. Copy that number to the value part of note #1.

[image] [image] [image]

```
*p = 42;
```

Look up `p` in your symbol table. That's note #3. *Now find the note with the number written in the value part of note #3*. That's the operation called *dereferencing*. It is denoted by the `*` in the notation above. Erase whatever is in the value part of *that* note (not the #3, the one #3 is *pointing at*) and write `42` instead.

[image] [image] [image]

```
*p = b;
```

Do this yourself. Here's what you should get:

[image] [image] [image]

```
p = &b;
```

Again, look up `p` and `b` in your symbol table (#3 and #2 respectively). Now take the **address part** of #2 (that's the operation represented by `&`, often called, unsurprisingly, the *address-of* operator) and copy it to the **value part** of #3 (of course erase what was there beforehand).

[image] [image] [image]

```
*p = 42;
```

Should be easy by now.

[image] [image] [image]

Now create another pointer under #4. File it in your symbol table as `q`.

```
q = NULL;
```

Find `q` (that's the #4 note) and write `note #0` in the value part. *Note that there is no note #0*. That's a null pointer. It doesn't point to any address.

*Caution: the standard doesn't mandate that the null pointer is actually represented is 0. It could have been `note #99999999` or `note #-1` or whatever, as long as it's distinct from all existing notes*

[image] [image] [image]
 [image]

```
p = q;
```

Do this yourself. Here's what you should get:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
*p = 42;
```

What should happen? Ostensibly you should take `p` (that's #3), find out which note it points to, and change that note. But it points to note #0 now, and there's no such note. You have invoked **undefined behaviour**. The C standard explicitly declines to specify what your program should do. In practice it is likely to crash with a message such as "segmentation fault (core dumped)" or "program <programname> has stopped working".

Comment: This is something I have started to write a long time ago as a tutorial on pointers. I have no idea if this format is appropriate for stackoverflow. Feel free to downvote if it isn't!

Comment: The notes could be smaller in height especially. Also, these could use an alt tag.

Comment: Now that we have a "documentation" section I'd expect this to be there, but I'm not familiar with it so maybe I'm wrong. Anyway. This is quite a nice analogy, only a few nitpicks: 1 - the null note should really read "nowhere" instead of "#0". The standard is very careful to treat null pointers as special, and *not* require them to actually be zero. And as you said, the null note's pointee is not a note at all! 2 - I personally find that the notes are *huge*, it hurts reading a bit. The color is... meh. (cont.)

Comment: is stackoverflow a tutorial plateform ? I take it a problem solving , and doubt removing plateform...

Comment: (cont.) 3 - you should mention early that each note is a variable. For now it's only comprehensible indirectly once we get to the "variable names" part. 4 - as this is a beginner-oriented question, maybe step a bit away from the standard in the null dereferencing part, and mention likely outcomes so a future SIGSEGV doesn't leave them scratching their head. All in all, this is nice. Thanks for taking the time to write this :)

Comment: @ShivamSharma Canonical Q&A written by experienced members from the PoV of a beginner are really useful -- if only as landing targets for redirecting duplicate questions from *actual* beginners.

Comment: @quentin ya you're right.. it really  be helpful for beginners who  traverse here to just find out the real results..

Comment: @Quentin 1. I decided that the null pointer should have the same format as other pointers, that is, "note #NNNN". 2. The pictures are 270 pixels wide and high, is this too large? 3. I specifically don't want to say that they must be variables (could be struct fields or array elements or some malloc'd memory) though I'm not firmly set on the wording. 4 I will add something to this effect.

Comment: @n.m. well on my 1080p only three of them fit in height. It's also quite a gap between the text describing what happens and the picture of "where" it happens. There are [smaller sticky notes formats](http://www.gresswell.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/G/1/G18044_7675.jpg) out there ;)

Comment: @Quentin I didn't find a good online sticky note image generator (ideally I wanted different fonts and customizable size). I may end up photographing a bunch of actual physical yellow notes for this.